# How to get continuous updates of firebase `childEventListener` from `repository` to `viewModel` using `flow`?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-mvvm, kotlin-flow

`view` observes `liveData` from `viewModel`, `viewModel` calls firebase `childEventListener` api to get updates from `repository`, `repository` is using `flow`,

1. How to send updates from `repository` to `viewModel`
2. How to make it robust enough so that it can survive against process death, idle time, configuration changes etc... without using `database`!
3. What will be the difference if we use `sharedFlow` instead of `stateFlow`?
4. How can we use `callbackFlow`?
5. Is there any disadvantages of using `callbackFlow` over `stateFlow`?

Comment: `viewModel` collects the flow via `repository`. `Repository` uses `callbackFlow`. When `viewModel` collects the result, it emits the `livedata` value using `liveDataScope`. `View` can observe this `liveData` and keep receiving updates. This way, `repository` does not expose `android` framework and we are managing the data through `viewModelScope`.

Comment: I think this [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FireApp) can help you find all the answers to your questions.